# EGit with Eclipse, what does this mean?

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

[image: git_changes_screenshot]

From this screenshot, what does the "box2" part mean?

Also, does the box before the "2" mean that I'm missing a font or something?? I think i saw somewhere that there should be an arrow icon before the number.

I assumed it means that there are 2 local changes that haven't been committed, but when I right-click on the repository and choose commit, I am informed that there are no changes to commit.

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That box is supposed to be an upwards or downwards arrow, since current software assumes that your OS can display Unicode fonts. (On WinXP, you'll have to install and select those if you haven't already).

An upwards means that your local 'master' branch is ahead of the branch it is tracking (probably 'origin/master'), the number indicates that it's ahead by 2 commits, i.e. you've made two commits which you havent pushed yet.

Analogously, a downward arrow means that that your local branch is behind, i.e. you've fetched from remote but not merged the new remote commits into your local 'master'.

Comment: See also the [comments on bug 372544](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=372544#c6) for how to change the fonts.